# Proving $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ $\iff$ there is $(x_n) \subset H$, with $||x_n||=1$ such that: $\lim_{n \to \infty} ||Ax_n-\lambda x_n||=0$

Tags: functional-analysis

I've been working on proving the following statement, but succeeded with only one direction.

> Let $A \in B(H)$ be a self-adjoint operator. Prove that $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ $\iff$ there is a sequence $(x_n) \subset H$, with $||x_n||=1$ for all $n$ such that: $\lim_{n \to \infty} ||Ax_n-\lambda x_n||=0$.

The $\Longleftarrow$ direction I accomplished by contradiction: if $A-\lambda I$ were invertible, then it must be bounded from below, and this is in contradiction with the given sequence.

I am not sure what to do with the other direction. I thought perhaps the spectral theorem might come in handy somehow because $A$ is self-adjoint, but I'm not sure how. I can't see much else that can be relevant with this hypothesis.

Any ideas?

Comment: If $B$ is self-adjoint (or normal) then $B$ is invertible iff there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\|Bv\|\ge c\|v\|$ for all $v\in H.$ Apply that to $B=A-\lambda I.$ The converse direction can be derived as follows: inequality implies that $B$ is injective and its range is closed. The orthogonal complement of the range is equal $\ker B$ , i.e. it is trivial. Hence $B$ is bijective, hence invertible. The boundedness of the inverse follows from the inequality. Contradicting the inequality gives a sequence $x_n$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|Bx_n\|\to 0.$